# Does Google Tango work with the PMD CamBoard pico flexx?

Tags: google-project-tango

Does the Google Tango API work with the CamBoard pico flexx board via USB-OTG on Android? Or only Tango devices which have the PMD sensor built in?

Answer (score 1):

Tango API is not supported non-Tango Android devices. Tango's software requires not only a depth camera, but also a fisheye camera and system level integration. Thus plugging in a depth sensor will not be able to run the Tango software stack.

Comment: does it really support USB-OTG? in the developer doc, it pretty much says that I need a 'Tango Device', and indeed, the Tango Core app from play store wouldn't install on my regular cell phone with the PMD Pico Flexx attached to it :(

Comment: sorry, I miss understood your question. I thought you meant using PMD sensor on an existing Tango device. I updated the answer above.